# Saving and storing the contents of a Panel dynamically

Tags: c#, winforms, image, user-interface, visual-studio-2012

I have a program where a user is able to create text boxes, and drag and drop images into a panel in windows forms, here the user can move the images about, resize it, delete them etc. Basically a very simple image editor.

What I want to do is have this work like a very simple PowerPoint program.

I am trying to work out if it is possible for a user to save the contents of the Panel that has these images (in pictureboxes) and textboxes. Then clear the panel and start over with new images and text, but go back to the previous panel and edit it if they wish.

So each panel in the program is basically a slide in PowerPoint.

At the moment I can save the panel as a Jpeg, and store these but this way I cant reload the panel and edit the contents as if it were a panel.

I hope I have explained the situation to some understandable degree.

Is it possible to do what I am trying or should I be approaching the problem differently?

Answer (score 5):

The way I would go about this is to define a class that stores all the information that makes up a slide (and as such, can represent the slide in your code), and then serialize a list of slides, called a Presentation, as an XML file.

Each slide is going to have a variable number of controls, which can be images, textboxes, ect, so lets define a control first:

```
public class MySlideClass
{
    public class Control
    {
        public Point Position       { get; set; }
        public Size  Size           { get; set; }
        public Color Background     { get; set; }
        public Color Forground      { get; set; }
        public Image Picture        { get; set; }
        public string Text          { get; set; }
        public float TextSize       { get; set; }
        public Point TextPosition   { get; set; }
        // ...
        public float Transparency   { get; set; }
        public bool  Visible        { get; set; }

        public Control()
        {
        }
    }

    public class Slide
    {
        [XmlAttribute]
        public string Name          { get; set; }
        //
        public string Title         { get; set; }
        public Size Size            { get; set; }
        public Color Background     { get; set; }
        public Color Forground      { get; set; }
        public float Transparency   { get; set; }
        public bool Visible         { get; set; }

        public List<Control> Children { get; set; }

        public Slide()
        {
        }
    }


    public MySlideClass()
    {
    }
}
```

Obviously, you can add/remove properties as your see fit.

Note the `{ get; set; }` and empty default constructor. Your class must consist of public properties (variables defined with the get/set) and have a empty default constructor for the `XMLSerializer` to be able to serialize your classes (you can still specify other constructors that arn't empty).

You would use the classes like so:

```
public void SaveSlideTest()
{
    // New control
    MySlideClass.Control newControl = new MySlideClass.Control();
    newControl.Position = new Point(20,30);
    newControl.Size     = new Size(75,25);
    newControl.Text     = "Image1";
    newControl.TextPosition= new Point(0,25);
    //ctl.Picture       = new Bitmap("image1.bmp");

    // Add control to children list
    List<MySlideClass.Control> childrenControls = new List<MySlideClass.Control>();
    childrenControls.Add(newControl);

    // New slide
    MySlideClass.Slide newSlide = new MySlideClass.Slide();
    newSlide.Name   = "Slide1";
    newSlide.Title  = "New Slide";
    newSlide.Size   = new Size(200,100);
    // Add child controls to slide
    newSlide.Children = childrenControls;

    // Add slide to presentation or 'slideshow'
    List<MySlideClass.Slide> mySlidePresentation = new List<MySlideClass.Slide>();
    mySlidePresentation.Add( newSlide );

    // Save presentation to XML
    SerializeObject("SavedSlidePresentation.xml",mySlidePresentation);
}
```

Your SavedSlidePresentation.xml looks like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfSlide xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <Slide Name="Slide1">
    <Title>New Slide</Title>
    <Size>
      <Width>200</Width>
      <Height>100</Height>
    </Size>
    <Background />
    <Forground />
    <Transparency>0</Transparency>
    <Visible>false</Visible>
    <Children>
      <Control>
        <Position>
          <X>20</X>
          <Y>30</Y>
        </Position>
        <Size>
          <Width>75</Width>
          <Height>25</Height>
        </Size>
        <Background />
        <Forground />
        <Text>Image1</Text>
        <TextSize>0</TextSize>
        <TextPosition>
          <X>0</X>
          <Y>25</Y>
        </TextPosition>
        <Transparency>0</Transparency>
        <Visible>false</Visible>
      </Control>
    </Children>
  </Slide>
</ArrayOfSlide>
```

Here are the serialize/deserialize functions:

```
public static List<MySlideClass.Slide> DeserializePresentation(string FileName)
{
    List<MySlideClass.Slide> returnList = new List<MySlideClass.Slide>();

    using(StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(FileName))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlReader = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<MySlideClass.Slide>));
        returnList = (List<MySlideClass.Slide>) xmlReader.Deserialize(streamReader);
    }
    return returnList;
}

// A generic object serializer
public static void SerializeObject(string Filename,object Obj)
{
    using(StreamWriter streamWriter = new StreamWriter(Filename))
    {
        XmlSerializer xmlSerializer = new XmlSerializer(Obj.GetType());
        xmlSerializer.Serialize(streamWriter,Obj);
    }
}
```

This should be more robust than a `Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`.

One important aspect to note:
If you decide to add a property to your Slide or Control class, the deserializer will not be able to deserialize the XML files with the older version of the data class.

In that case you could either 1) convert the older version XML files manually or otherwise, or 2) Implement the `ISerializable` interface in your class (reccomended).

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. How do you record the type of control, for example textbox or picturebox?

Comment: @kev3kev3, the easiest way to do that would be to create a new class similar to `MySlideClass.Control`, name it something like TextboxControl and modify it to contain the variables that you need. If you try to make new derived classes from a 'control' class, serializer will throw an error. If you MUST use derived classes, then you have two options: 1) Add an XmlInclude attribute above the base class, one for each derived type, like so:   `[XmlInclude(typeof(TextboxControl))]` 2) Use a custom serializer when serializiing: 'new XmlSerializer(typeof(Control),new Type[]{typeof(TextboxControl)});'

Comment: @AdamWhiteHat
Where is this function SerializeObject("SavedSlidePresentation.xml",mySlidePresentation);

Comment: @prakashkumarjha I have now added the `SerializeObject` function, nice catch.

Answer (score 1):

I made a similar kind of project before and I created two dictionaries to hold all the data

```
// Dictionary which Holds all the Info for the shapes in a Particular Slide
Dictionary<Int32, ShapeInfo> slideInfoDict = new Dictionary<Int32, ShapeInfo>();

// Dictionary which Holds all the Info for the all the shapes in the all the slides
Dictionary<Int32, SlideInfo> appInfoDict = new Dictionary<Int32, SlideInfo>();
```

My "ShapeInfo" class has all the information about various shapes (Table, Rect, Image etc) 
The key (Int32) of this shapeInfoDict was the selected shape.

Class "SlideInfo" holds all the information about that particular slide.
The key (Int32) of this slideInfoDict was selected Slide.

Hope that Helps.